# Call to a member function get() on null "Symfony Php"

Tags: php, symfony, device-detection

I'am trying to get details of devices who access our application. I have integrated "[MobileDetectBundle](https://github.com/suncat2000/MobileDetectBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md)" bundle in php symfony 3.4 version and followed the steps provided in the documentation. But I am getting the following error at this line

```
$mobileDetector = $this->get('mobile_detect.mobile_detector');
```

Code Snippet :

```
$mobileDetector = $this->get('mobile_detect.mobile_detector');
$mobileDetector->isMobile();
$mobileDetector->isTablet();
```

Error :

```
"Call to a member function get() on null"
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with `$this` which assumed to be an instance of your controller class, but is null which means you are calling that somewhere (maybe inside controller constructor) where there is no `$this` yet.

the solution indeed is Dependency Injection. you would better inject that service into your controller (which is defined as a service automatically through auto-wiring) and use it inside your controller:

```
class MyController
{
    // ...

    protected $mobileDetector;

    public function __construct(MobileDetector $mobileDetector)
    {
        $this->mobileDetector = $mobileDetector;
        $this->mobileDetector->isMobile();
        $this->mobileDetector->isTablet();
    }

    // ...
}
```